# Modeshape 2.8 programmatic configuration

Tags: authentication, configuration, jcr, modeshape

Hi i what to do a programmatic configuration of repository, because most of the parameter for configuration in repository can only determine in run time.

Seems like i am unable to use anonymous credential  when im try to print the session it throws NPE
code below

```
   config.repositorySource("store")
          .usingClass(DiskSource.class)
          .setProperty("repositoryRootPath", "c:/x/repo1")
          .setProperty("defaultWorkspaceName","default");

          config.repository("content")
          .setOption(JcrRepository.Option.USE_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ON_FAILED_LOGIN, "true")
          .setSource("store");

    Session session  =  engine.getRepository("content").login("default");
```

Can I add Custom authenticator to JcrConfiguration?

Comment: What's the stack trace from the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to configure a ModeShape engine is to use the JcrConfiguration object, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE28/Configuring+ModeShape#ConfiguringModeShape-ProgrammaticConfiguration). This appears to be what you're doing, so that part is right.

Once you've created your configuration, you can check it for problems:

```
if ( !configuration.getProblems().isEmpty() ) {
    for ( Problem problem : configuration.getProblems() ) {
         // Report these problems!
    }
}
```

Assuming there are no problems, you can then use your configuration to create a new JcrEngine instance (see [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE28/Using+the+JCR+API+with+ModeShape#UsingtheJCRAPIwithModeShape-ModeShape%27s%7B%7BJcrEngine%7D%7D)):

```
JcrConfiguration config = ...
JcrEngine engine = config.build();
engine.start();
```

Then, look up your repository by its name and log in using the JCR API:

```
javax.jcr.Repository repository = engine.getRepository("Name of repository");

Credentials credentials = ...; // JCR credentials
String workspaceName = ...;  // Name of repository workspace
Session session = repository.login(credentials,workspaceName);
```

Comment: hi randall thanks for the quick response is there a programmatic way to authenticator